# Receiving 429 error from planet api

Tags: planet

I've just signed up for a **planet API** explorer account, and after downloading my first image, I continuously receive a [429 response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) when attempting to activate an item.

I'm using the activation script given here: https://developers.planet.com/docs/quickstart/downloading-imagery/#asset-activation

I'm requesting **REOrthoTile item types**. I've read the API returns 429 when you've exceeded your rate, however, I most definitely haven't exceeded any rate, as I only posted once today and still received a 429.

Is there any other reason I could be receiving a 429?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 429 HTTP error is used to indicate either a rate limit or a quota limit has been reached.

For free accounts, the daily quota is 4000 square kilometers in California. Outside California, you get a one-time allocation of 1000 square km. Currently, you have used a little over 600 square km from the latter, and since RapidEye tiles are 25×25 km (625 square km), you don't have enough quota for one. PlanetScope scenes are smaller you should be able to get one or two of them.

Daily quotas reset at midnight UTC.

Comment: I’ve attempted to download a single RapidEye tile for the past 3 days, every day, receiving a 429 every time. Are my quotas not resetting? How can I check my quotas?

Comment: Fixed my answer as I had your account details a little wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize it was a one time quota of 1000km, the way they describe the explorer account is unlimited access for two weeks. This is indeed why I was receiving the 429.

Comment: Do you recall where you saw the description that was misleading about the quota limits? It's possible there's some old language somewhere that needs fixing!

Comment: It was in the email I received upon activating my account, but now that I read it again it does seem to provide correct information about quotas, I was just confused:

Imagery Access
PlanetScope, RapidEye, Landsat 8 and Sentinel-2 datasets are at your fingertips.

View daily imagery and Planet's entire PlanetScope and RapidEye archive at full zoom (3-5m/px)
Download up to 1,000 sq km of imagery through the Planet GUI or API
View SkySat imagery at limited resolution (30-40m/px) or download sample imagery here. I believed this meant I could download up to 1,000 sq km a day, not total.

Comment: 5 months after last comment, I ran into a similar issue. Following the quick start guides, I simply applied the same to other areas and got a 429. After reading this and going back, I see what is going on, but somehow leading up to this I also misunderstood the initial access. Might be good if the guides went a little further to cover pulling worldwide data.